# addition between classes using radd method

Tags: python-3.x

I have two different classes, and I want to define the addition of them only in one class, and define both `__add__` and `__radd__` for that class (in my example below, that's `ExampleClass2`. I DO NOT want to create an `__add__` method that works for `ExampleClass1` to add `ExampleClass2`.

As it is right now it just ignores it. I also tried with raising error, but that didn't work either.

```
class ExampleClass1:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            print('other was an int')
        
        
class ExampleClass2:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, ExampleClass1):
            print("it's working")
            
    __radd__ = __add__
    
a = ExampleClass1('q')

b = ExampleClass2('w')

a+b
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`__radd__` is only called if the left object does not have an `__add__` method, or that method does not know how to add the two objects (which it flags by returning `NotImplemented`). Both classes have an `__add__` method, which do not return `NotImplemented`. Therefore the `__radd__` method would never be called.

Comment: Ah, NotImplemented, that was exactly the functionality i was looking for. Nice

Answer (score 11):

Suppose you are implementing a class that you want to act like a number via operator overloading. So you implement **add** in your class, and now expressions like `myobj + 4` can work as you want and yield some result. This is because `myobj + 4` is interpreted as `myobj.__add__(4)`, and your custom method can do whatever it means to add 4 to your custom class.

However, what about an expression like `4 + myobj` which is really `(4).__add__(myobj)`? The 4 is an instance of a Python built-in type and its **add** method doesn't know anything about your new type, so it will return a special value NotImplemented. (The interpreter recognizes this special value coming from **add** and raises a TypeError exception which kills your program, which is the behavior you'd actually see, rather than the special value being returned.)

It would suck for operator overloading if `myobj + 4` was valid but `4 + myobj` was invalid. That's arbitrary and restrictive — addition is supposed to be commutative. Enter `__radd__`. Python will first try `(4).__add__(myobj)`, and if that returns NotImplemented Python will check if the right-hand operand implements **radd**, and if it does, it will call `myobj.__radd__(4)` rather than raising a TypeError. And now everything can proceed as usual, as your class can handle the case and implement your behavior, rather than the built-in type's **add** which is fixed and doesn't know about your class.

Example:

```
class X:
    
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.num + other.num
    
    __radd__ = __add__


class Y:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)


x = X(5)
y = Y(10)

print(x+y)

print(y+x)
```

Answer (score 9):

> These functions `__radd__` are only called if the left operand does
>   not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of
>   different types. For example,

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num
```

---

```
class Y:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num

  def __radd__(self, other_obj):
    return Y(self.num+other_obj.num)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.num)
```

---

```
>>> x = X(2)
>>> y = Y(3)
>>> print(x+y)
5
>>>
>>> print(y+x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-9d7469decd6e> in <module>()
----> 1 print(y+x)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Y' and 'X'
```