# Auto-generating the overloaded operators?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Consider the following implementation of a vector object with all vector operations in Python:

```
import operator

class Vector:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._vals = value.copy()


    @classmethod
    def _op(cls, this, that, oper, rev=False):

        assert isinstance(this, cls)

        if rev:
            op = lambda a, b : oper(b, a)
        else:
            op = oper

        if isinstance(that, list):
            result = [op(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(this._vals, that)]
        elif isinstance(that, cls):
            result = [op(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(this._vals, that._vals)]
        else:
            # assume other is scalar
            result = [op(x, that) for x in this._vals]

        return cls(result)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.add, False)


    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.add, True)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.sub, False)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.sub, True)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.mul, False)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.mul, True)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.truediv, False)

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return Vector._op(self, other, operator.truediv, True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._vals)
```

As it is evident, all the overloaded operator (`__add__`, `__radd__`, ...) have exactly the same code, except is for the `oper` and `rev` parameters passed to the private class method `_op`.

Is there a way to avoid all the copy-paste and automatically (or semi-automatically) those operators?

Comment: R-version is only used if no normal version is available. See answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126766/addition-between-classes-using-radd-method

Answer (score 0):

First thing: classmethods are available on instances too, so you should write your methods as

```
def __someop__(self, other):
    return self._op(self, other, ...)
```

Alternatively, it's easy to get an object's type (`cls = type(obj)`), so unless you have other reasons to make `_op` a classmethod, you could just make it an instance method.

Now for your question: technically, you could use a custom metaclass or a class decorator to create the methods, ie:

```
class VectorType(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
        todo = [
            # name, operator, reverse
            ("__add__", operator.add, False), 
            ("__sub__", operator.sub, False),
            # etc
            ]
         for name, oper, rev in todo:
             # avoids overriding already defined methods
             if name not in attrs:
                 def f(self, other):  
                     return cls._op(self, other, oper=oper, rev=rev)
                 attrs[name] = f

          return type.__new__(meta, name,   bases, attr) 

class Vector(metaclass=VectorType):
    # etc
```

but this really won't improve your existing code, unless you have a lot of (unrelated) classes with this scheme, and even then a plain mixin class would work just as well.

If you only have the issue for this single class, your current code is is clear, simple, readable and explicit, IOW perfectly pythonic.

Comment: Aren't special methods always looked up using the object's class? That means that they couldn't just be made instance methods, as you claim.

Comment: @martineau I'm afraid I dont get your comment.... special methods are only looked up on classes yes but it doesn't mean they must be classmethods (and they shouldn't actually) - and the only method I suggested turning into an instance method isn't a magic method anyway.

Comment: @martineau also it looks like you are confusing "instance methods" (iow ordinary methods, defined on the class and taking the instance as first param) with "per-instance methods" iow methods added as instance attributes (which are not part of my answer obviously)