# How define operator add in class Interval to be able to add a number to an interval in python

Tags: python, operators, addition

In class Interval I defined operator `__add__` to add two Intervals like this

```
a = Interval(1,2)
b = Interval(10, 20)
a + b
```

the result is an interval like

```
c = Interval(11, 22)
```

i.e `[1,2] + [10, 20] = [11, 22]`

Now I want to add a number to an Interval like this:

```
1 + Interval(4, 8)
```

i.e `1 + [4, 8] = [5, 9]` and result become an interval `c = Interval(5, 9)`

but I have no idea how do that! Is it even possible?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126766/addition-between-classes-using-radd-method

Answer (score 0):

As the left operator doesn't handle addition with `Interval`, implement it in `Interval.__radd__`

> `__radd__` is only called if the left object does not have an `__add__` method, or that method does not know how to add the two objects (which it flags by returning `NotImplemented`)

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, int):      # Interval + int
        return Interval(self.start + other, self.end + other)
    if isinstance(other, Interval): # Interval + Interval
        return Interval(self.start + other.start, self.end + other.end)
    raise NotImplementedError()

def __radd__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, int):  # int + Interval
        return Interval(self.start + other, self.end + other)
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

```
a = Interval(1, 2)
b = Interval(10, 20)

print(a + b)  # __add__
print(a + 1)  # __add__

print(1 + a)  # __radd__
```

```
[11;22]
[2;3]
[2;3]
```